# how to update table with session variable in php pdo?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i have one table called post_data, In that i want to update columns based on session variable.

this is my query.

```
$id = $_SESSION['userSession'];

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("UPDATE post_data 
                                      set 
                                      cam_name='$cname', 
                                      cam_model ='$model', 
                                      cam_rent='$rent',
                                      cam_img='$upic',
                                      mobile='$umob'
                                      upd_date='$jdate'
                                      where userID='$id'
                                      ");

        $stmt->bindParam(':cname',$camname);
        $stmt->bindParam(':model',$modelname);
        $stmt->bindParam(':rent',$rentpday);
        $stmt->bindParam(':upic',$userpic);
        $stmt->bindParam(':umob',$usermob);
        $stmt->bindParam(":jdate",$upd_date);

        if($stmt->execute())
        {

            $successMSG = "Record saved success";
        }
        else
        {
            $errMSG = "error while inserting....";
        }
```

this is runQuery() implementation in USER class

```
public function runQuery($sql)
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    return $stmt;
}
```

i got error like this

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'upd_date='2017-09-24 21:29:18' where ' at line 8 in C:\xampp\htdocs\DSLR_proj\profile.php:97

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `,` just after `mobile='$umob'`.

Also, `$cname` is not same `:cname`. I would prefer to use placeholder as `?` instead of any specific string to avoid any typo.

Also, you are missing binding for `userID` column.

```
UPDATE post_data 
       set cam_name=?,cam_model =?, cam_rent=?, cam_img=?, mobile=?, upd_date=? 
       where userID=?

    $stmt->bindParam(1,$camname);
    $stmt->bindParam(2,$modelname);
    $stmt->bindParam(3,$rentpday);
    $stmt->bindParam(4,$userpic);
    $stmt->bindParam(5,$usermob);
    $stmt->bindParam(6,$upd_date);
    $stmt->bindParam(7,$id);  // you are missing this as well
```

Comment: TBH I prefer named parameters.  Yes there is a potential issue with typos, but also with positional parameters, it's not as easy to see that you've got a parameter in the wrong order.  After all `3,$modelname` is not as easy to debug as `:rent,$modelName`.

Comment: @lohithkumar will you  give me one favour ?

Comment: @NigelRen correct. I didn't said. You MUST. So, it's individual choice, how they are comfortable. As both works as same.

Comment: @NigelRen will you help me  ?

Comment: Ya tell me bro.